# Bitbucket Control Freak error message that a branch cannot be created as commits on the new branch must arrive via pull-request

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

My Bitbucket users normally use the Bitbucket UI to create a new branch.  The Bitbucket plugin, Control Freak, has been enabled and the global branch permissions section has been setup to "Always Require Pull-Requests" on branches.  When users try to create a new branch based off of an existing one, a Control Freak message is displayed that the branch creation was cancelled as "Commits on the new branch MUST arrive via a pull-request and the starting-point (release/2024.1) for this new branch has never passed through a pull-request.".  What are the steps needed to resolve this error?  Is it that the parent branch needs all current commits on it to go through a pull-request first and then create the new branch off of it?  I am not sure what steps are needed.  Thanks.

Comment: What branch are you creating `release/2024.1` from? Posting your branch model to your question could help. Also, not an answer but Bitbucket has built-in checks for protected branches to only receive the updates via pull requests, have you had a chance to explore them before using custom plugins?

Comment: Maybe instead of having that global rule you can apply that rule solely to certain branches like `main` and `release/*`, thus allowing users to push new branches to the repo?

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for taking a look at the question.  The release/2024.1 was being created from a tag.

We use the plugin because we can set it at a global level for all repositories as well as it enforces other policies globally.